Error when building. (something related with generateStaticParams() or API)
When I use localhost:3000 as the baseURL in my project, the build fails, but it works perfectly when I use the Vercel production build URL. Here is my code:
import { Blog, getBlogs, getBlog } from "@/services/blog";
import { Clock } from "@phosphor-icons/react/dist/ssr";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  try {
    const data: Blog[] = await getBlogs();
    return data?.map((post?: Blog) => ({
      params: {
        title: `${post?.title.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}-${post?.id}`,
      },
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating static params:", error);
    return [];
  }
}

const SigleBlogPage = async ({ params }: { params: { title: string } }) => {
  const id = params.title.split("-").pop();

  if (!id) {
    return null;
  }

  const post = await getBlog(id);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto border-b border-gray-200 pb-2">
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">{post?.title}</h1>
        <div className="text-gray-700 mb-2 md:mb-4">
          <p>{post?.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="text-sm text-gray-500 flex items-end justify-between">
          <span className="flex sm:gap-2 flex-col sm:flex-row">
            <span>{post?.author}</span>
            <span className="hidden sm:block">•</span>
            <span>{post?.date}</span>
          </span>
          <span className="flex gap-2 items-center">
            <span className="hidden sm:block">{post?.tags?.join(", ")}. - </span>
            <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
              <span>{Math.ceil(post?.description?.length / 1000)} min</span>
              <Clock size={15} className="text-gray-500" />
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="prose lg:prose-xl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SigleBlogPage;

Blog Service Code
import axiosInstance from "@/lib/axiosInstance";

class BlogError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "BlogError";
  }
}

export interface Blog {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  date: string;
  description: string;
  tags: string[];
  imageDescription: string;
}

export const getBlogs = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("/api/blog/posts");
    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    switch (error.response?.status) {
      case 500:
        throw new BlogError("Internal Server Error");
      default:
        throw new BlogError("Error fetching blogs");
    }
  }
};

export const getBlog = async (id: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`/api/blog/posts/${id}`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    switch (error.response?.status) {
      case 500:
        throw new BlogError("Internal Server Error");
      default:
        throw new BlogError("Error fetching blog");
    }
  }
};

Axios Instance
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;

Build Output with Localhost
When I run the build locally with localhost:3000:
npm run build

> cmmg@0.1.0 build
> next build

▲ Next.js 14.2.4
- Environments: .env.local

Creating an optimized production build ...
✓ Compiled successfully
✓ Linting and checking validity of types
Collecting page data  .Error generating static params: a [BlogError]: Error fetching blogs
    at n (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\[title]\page.js:1:9474)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object._ [as generateStaticParams] (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\[title]\page.js:1:6633)
    at async buildParams (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1026:40)
    at async C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1043:33
    at async C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1177:114
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
✓ Collecting page data
Generating static pages (4/27)  [=   ]Error fetching news: K [AggregateError]
    at K.from (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\chunks\712.js:11:11099)
    at y.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\chunks\712.js:13:8636)
    at y.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at d.<computed> (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\chunks\712.js:1:13567)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:492:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at aF.request (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\chunks\712.js:13:20551)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async i (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\(auth)\page.js:1:3192)
    at async l (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\(auth)\page.js:1:3339) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errors: [

Build Output with Vercel BASE URL
When I deploy and build using Vercel URL (for API request, etc...):
npm run build

> cmmg@0.1.0 build
> next build

▲ Next.js 14.2.4
- Environments: .env.local

Creating an optimized production build ...
✓ Compiled successfully
✓ Linting and checking validity of types
✓ Collecting page data
✓ Generating static pages (27/27)
✓ Collecting build traces
✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    190 B          99.1 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          871 B            88 kB
├ ○ /admin                               162 B          87.3 kB
├ ƒ /admin/logs                          162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /admin/news                          2.73 kB         116 kB
├ ○ /analiticas                          162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /api                                 0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/auth/send-code                  0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/auth/verify-code                0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/banner                          0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/blog/posts                      0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/blog/posts/[id]                 0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/login                           0 B                0 B
├ ○ /api/logout                          0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/logs                            0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/news                            0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/register                        0 B                0 B
├ ƒ /api/user                            0 B                0 B
├ ○ /artistas                            190 B          99.1 kB
├ ○ /blog                                190 B          99.1 kB
├ ● /blog/[title]                        162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /catalogo                            162 B          87.

3 kB
├ ○ /contabilidad                        162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /engagement                          162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /general                             162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /informes                            162 B          87.3 kB
├ ○ /login                               1.92 kB         122 kB
└ ○ /proyectos                           162 B          87.3 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87.1 kB
  ├ chunks/23-d5dfd65ed9ffc36f.js        31.5 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-ec3e518d3a192d14.js  53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.96 kB
ƒ Middleware                             43.7 kB

Why does the build fail locally when using localhost:3000 but works perfectly with the Vercel production build? How can I resolve this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Edit, another common error traceback when I change the way of fetching.

> cmmg@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Environments: .env.local

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
   Collecting page data  ..Error generating static params: a [BlogError]: Error fetching blogs
    at n (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\[title]\page.js:1:9332)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object._ [as generateStaticParams] (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\[title]\page.js:1:6633)
    at async buildParams (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1026:40)
    at async C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1043:33
    at async C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1177:114
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (6/27)  [=   ]a [BlogError]: Error fetching blogs
    at i (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:6493)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:5680) {
  digest: '3543585591'
}
a [BlogError]: Error fetching blogs
    at i (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:6493)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:5680) {
  digest: '3543585591'
}
a [BlogError]: Error fetching blogs
    at i (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:6493)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:5680) {
  digest: '3543585591'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/blog". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

BlogError: Error fetching blogs
    at i (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:6493)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\cmmg\.next\server\app\blog\page.js:1:5680)
 ✓ Generating static pages (27/27)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /blog/page: /blog

If I use an external example blog API also works fine.
import BlogEntry from "@/components/BlogEntry";
import { Blog, getBlogs } from "@/services/blog";

export default async function Page() {
  // const data: Blog[] = await getBlogs();
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  const data = await res.json();

  

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4 sm:px-[5%] px-4 sm:px-[5%] md:px-[8%] lg:px-[15%]">
      <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-12 md:gap-8">
        {data?.map((post: Blog) => (
          <BlogEntry post={post} key={post.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

import { Blog, getBlogs, getBlog } from "@/services/blog";
import { Clock } from "@phosphor-icons/react/dist/ssr";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  try {
    // const data: Blog[] = await getBlogs();
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data?.map((post?: Blog) => ({
      params: {
        title: `${post?.title.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}-${post?.id}`,
      },
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating static params:", error);
    return [];
  }
}

const SigleBlogPage = async ({ params }: { params: { title: string } }) => {
  const id = params.title.split("-").pop();

  if (!id) {
    return null;
  }

  // const post = await getBlog(id);
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  const data = await res.json();

  const post = data.find((post: Blog) => post.id === Number(id));


  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto border-b border-gray-200 pb-2">
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">{post?.title}</h1>
        <div className="text-gray-700 mb-2 md:mb-4">
          <p>{post?.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="text-sm text-gray-500 flex items-end justify-between">
          <span className="flex sm:gap-2 flex-col sm:flex-row">
            <span>{post?.author}</span>
            <span className="hidden sm:block">•</span>
            <span>{post?.date}</span>
          </span>
          <span className="flex gap-2 items-center">
            <span className="hidden sm:block">
              {post?.tags?.join(", ")}. -{" "}
            </span>
            <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
              <span>{Math.ceil(post?.description?.length / 1000)} min</span>
              <Clock size={15} className="text-gray-500" />
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="prose lg:prose-xl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SigleBlogPage;


errors: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1673:16)
        at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 3000
    },
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1673:16)
        at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3000
    }
  ],

Same in other project
It get solved if I publish the App without any API call, an then, uploading the full app. Is like if the build need the API working to build it successfully. Happen always when I use SSR.


What service is (meant to be) running on localhost:3000?

The entire NextJs14 app I guess? but when trying to generate the blog static files it explode for some reason locally, but when I deploy it on Vercel or locally but using the Vercel App URL as baseURL, works fine.

The traceback says "Error fetching news" but the code you show doesn't have that error..?

Check the edit.  When removing the News it come with this. But in Vercel and with npm run dev works perfect.

I think you should temporarily get rid of all of that error handling – as it is, you (or we) have no way of knowing what the actual errors are, all we know is we get to your error handler.

pretty much the same but says [AggregateError] instead of [BlogError]

in the Axios Instance their is no need to use baseURL as whatever would be the parameter of the URL it will automatically get appended to the current URL
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;

or else you can even simply call the api
const response = await axios.get(`/api/blog/posts/${id}`);

by using this the parameters will get appended to the current URL wether its an localhost or an production URL

if i do that it show that is fetching localhost/api/blogs/posts, not any posrt

can you show me the error screen shot

I added other example and a possible hint.
